# How do you speed up the iPhone Synchronization with iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync

Every time I connect my iPhone to my computer, it takes like 10 to 15 minutes to even begin syncing.  This is horribly inconvenient and I would like to speed it up.  Are there any changes that I can make for this to occur?

**More Info**
After plugging in my iPhone, iTunes seems to open up fairly quickly (just as fast as my iPod Nano).  The actual Synchronization process does not start for a while though for some reason...  I am running Windows Vista...

**Even More Info**
It appears that this is the iPhone backup process.  By disabling the backup process for the phone, I should in theory get quicker synchronization.  Have not tried this yet, but will tonight.

Comment: iTunes on Windows or on a Mac?

Comment: Vista... Added to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you initiate the sync faster manually or is it taking its sweet time just recognizing the phone?

- I don't think this is what you are looking for, but here is a link about [decreasing long sync times](http://algorizms.blogspot.com/2007/09/fix-for-iphone-sync-times-in-vista.html) (might be helpful for you if your computer is taking a long time looking for things to -possibly- sync)
- [Another possibility](http://www.geardiary.com/2008/07/27/speed-up-itunes-sync-of-your-iphone-or-touch-by-only-selectively-sending-diagnostic-data-to-apple/)
- [And another?](http://blog.jhong.org/2008/08/does-your-iphone-take-forever-to.html)

Comment: I'll add more info in the question...

Comment: When I force the manual to occur after the auto has finished, it seems to go fairly quick.

Comment: RSolberg: I think iTunes might be doing a poor job of scouring your computer looking for stuff (especially images) that might need to be synced.

Comment: Thanks... I'll test these out over the weekend to see if those help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows the most likely suspect is photo syncing (assuming you have that enabled). On Vista, iTunes mayhave to scan folders to see which pictures to sync, and that may take a while. If you currently sync photo's from folders, try disabling photo syncing and see if that makes the problem go away.

If it doesn't, you should investigate what is causing the long sync by disabling everything that syncs (Contacts, Calendars, Movies, Photo's, Music, et cetera), and then turn them on one by one.